# Azure Function reading excel (xlsx) file

Tags: excel, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I have to import excel file into Azure SQL. It is quite frequent activity, so can't use wizard or manual process. The file contains 8000 rows and 95 columns. I am thinking to use Azure Functions but reading excel using openxml is taking too much time (evening locally). Do I have any other option beside openxml and optimizing below code?

Code:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument workbook =
                         SpreadsheetDocument.Open(uploadedFile, false))
{
    var sheet = ExcelUtilities.GetFirstSheet(workbook);
    var workSheet = sheet.Worksheet;
    var sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
    IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

    foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(0))
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(ExcelUtilities.GetCellValue(workbook, cell));
    }

    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < rows.Count(); rowIndex++)
    {
        var row = rows.ElementAt(rowIndex);
        DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
        {
            tempRow[i] = ExcelUtilities.GetCellValue(workbook, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
    }
}
```

**Constraints**:

- I think interop.excel or OLEDB can't be used in Azure Functions (as per this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155350/3633589 Microsoft.Ace providers are not available)
- OPENROWSET is also not an option

Answer (score -1):

If you can put/upload that Excel file on a storage account, you can use BULK INSERT on Azure SQL Database.

The following example uses an external data source pointing to a container (named week3) in an Azure storage account.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoicesContainer
    WITH (
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://newinvoices.blob.core.windows.net/week3',
        CREDENTIAL = UploadInvoices
    );
```

Using BULK INSERT, do not use the container name in the file description:

```
BULK INSERT Colors2
FROM 'inv-2017-01-19.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoicesContainer',
      FORMAT = 'CSV');
```

If you still want to use an Azure Function for this task, [here](https://github.com/yorek/AzureFunctionUploadToSQL) you will find an full example.

Comment: CSV is a type of Excel file.